# zipWithIndex rdd with initial value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD like this:

```
+----------+--------+
|firstName |lastName|
+----------+--------+
|      john|   smith|
|      anna|  tourde|
+----------+--------+
```

I wouldLike to create a new column as we can do with zipWithIndex but giving and initial value of 8.

```
+----------+--------+-----+
|firstName |lastName|index|
+----------+--------+-----+
|      john|   smith|    8|
|      anna|  tourde|    9|
+----------+--------+-----+
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().map { case (v, ind) =>
  (v, ind + 8)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `zipWithIndex` and convert back to dataframe as below

```
val df1 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index + 8)
},
// Create schema for index column
StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false)))
```